# how can I separate individual letters from an onChange event in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input, text, letter

I'm new to React and I have a problem which I don't know how to solve.

I have a state which tracks what I type on the textInput. But when I console.log the input that I type on the textInput, it shows the whole chunks like 'a', 'ab', 'abc' as I type. I want to be able to have control over each input I type like 'a' 'b' 'c', not the whole input like 'abc'. For this, I've tried the map and split function, which made some errors, unfortunately.

Can anyone offer some advice? I'm attaching some of the lines below.

```
const Words = () => {
  const [correctLetters, setCorrectLetters] = useState([]);
  const correctLettersHandler = (input) => {
  //console.log(input) -> it shows the whole inputs
  //const letter = input.map((letter) => letter.split("")); -> failed try
  setCorrectLetters(input);
  }
  return (
    <View>
     <TextInput
       value={correctLetters}
       onChangeTedt={correctLettersHandler}
    </View>
 }
```

Comment: use `onKeyPress`, `onKeyUp`, or `onKeyDown` depending on which part of the key pressing process you want to interrupt

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you take a look at [The KeyboardEvent Object](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/obj_keyboardevent.asp) to get a full insight on the keyboard events.

At the bottom there are the event types that belong to the KeyboardEvent Object (already mentioned by Derek in a comment to the question):

- [onkeydown](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/event_onkeydown.asp), the event that occurs when the user is pressing a key
- [onkeypress](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/event_onkeypress.asp), the event that occurs when the user presses a key
- [onkeyup](https://www.w3schools.com/JSREF/event_onkeyup.asp), the event that occurs when the user releases a key